# ‘class MyClass’ does not name a type when trying to define a static struct instance

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to define/declare a static struct instance but I keep getting the error `test.cc:3:1: error: ‘mine’ in ‘class MyClass’ does not name a type` when I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -c test.cc`

This is what my code looks like:

```
//test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <stdint.h>

struct my_struct {
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t bar;
};

class MyClass {
public:
    static const struct my_struct mine;
};


#endif
```

```
//test.cc
#include "test.h"

MyClass::mine = {1, 2};
```

Comment: `my_struct MyClass::mine = {1, 2};` . A variable declaration needs to start with its type.

Comment: In C++ you don't need to use `class` or `struct` when declaring instances.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you need to use `struct StructName` to declare an object.

But in C++, both `struct` and `class` before declarations are unnecessary.